# How to solve XCode swipe gesture to go to previous / next file freeze editor?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

Since this morning I'm facing a really annoying bug in XCode 5 on Mavericks :

I'm heavily used to swipe from left to right with two fingers on the MacBook trackpad to go to the XCode editor previous / next files.
BUT, now, doing this totally freeze the editor after having just moved for something like 5 px.
After that I have to close XCode and reopen it to make the editor work again.

Pressing the previous / next button works wel since it doesn't trigger this buggy animation.

Did anyone had this problem before or has any clue to solve it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact this problem is affecting other swipe gesture like the previous / next swipe in Safari.

I found a way to fix this on Apple Support Forum, by resetting the NVRAM.

> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>alt ⌥</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in next step.
> 3. Turn on the computer and immediately press and hold the <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>alt ⌥</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys before the gray screen appears.
> 4. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
> 5. Release the keys.
> 6. When your Mac finishes starting up, you might want to open System Preferences and adjust settings that have been reset, such as sound volume, display resolution, startup disk selection, or time zone.

Apple support: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: This issue suddenly started happening to me in Xcode, and this solution appears to have worked. Many thanks for posting it here!

Comment: This popped up right after I updated to Xcode 7. It's has been bugging me for a month! It works!

Answer (score 6):

For me, in Xcode 8.3.3 and Xcode 9, it started working after

1. Go to the system preferences
2. Go to Trackpad
3. Select and deselect "Tap to click"

Comment: Awesome answer.  This also fixes the left-swipe issue on Apple mouse where it was requiring three left swipes to be recognized.